# How to create new c++ object in gdb prompt via new operator

Tags: c++, gdb

How to create c++ object via new operator in gdb.
I am looking for something similar to

option-1) `(gdb) call new ClassType()` 
or
option-2) `(gdb) set $obj = new ClassType()`

But both of these options failing in gdb.

Comment: What happens when you use option-1 or option-2?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have mentioned both of above fail with error in gdb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
set var $new = malloc(sizeof(class ClassType))
call ClassType::ClassType($var)
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060099/how-to-call-constructor-in-gdb-for-pretty-printers if that didn't work